# Http post request-body

Tags: http-post

I'm tring to use lua to write a script to fetch some data from the website: www.baidu.com(which is popular in China), but it require authentication and anyone can signup the site.When I sign in the site , I use Fiddler to capture the session, and I found that the request-body have few variable parameters, like this:

```
ppui_logintime=14084&charset=UTF-8&codestring=&token=9fcf00d59b6b9860937a70c221??95d818&isPhone=false&index=0&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.baidu.com%2F&safeflg=0&staticpage??=https%3A%2F%2Fpassport.baidu.com%2Fv2Jump.html&loginType=1&tpl=mn&callback=paren??t.bdPass.api.login._postCallback&username=test&password=test&verifycode=&mem_pass??=on
```

The ppui_logintime and token field value, They get from where? And what are they used to do?

Any help / advice / suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The values come from the HTML webform that users log in to the site with.  It contains hidden fields, not just the fields the user sees onscreen.  When the webserver delivers the HTML to the browser, those hidden fields contain the values that get submitted back to the webserver along with the values that the user types in.  That is how HTML webforms work in general.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Now I want to sign in the site using a script(like curl or other language) to fetch some data.How should I do? I had searched with google, but I can't find a full example of code, so I'm only half-aware of what I need to be doing.

Comment: You would have to download the HTML for the login page first, manally parse out all of the webform field names and values, fill in the credential field values you need, then submit everything to the server.  There is no single code to do all of that. Curl can download the HTML and submit back to the server, but you have to do the HTML parsing yourself.